# How do I SELECT two distinct columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I want to be able to select two distinct from col1 and col2 ordered by id.

I'm struggling to do this because when I write the following SQL query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM table
ORDER BY id
```

I can't ORDER BY id because it's not in the SELECT statement but if I put id in the SELECT statement it will take the DISTINCT id, col1 and col2. Which is basically the whole table as it is since the id column is unique.

How do I do this?

Comment: What DB engine do you really use?

Comment: Provide table's DDL and sample data in textual form and desured result for this data.

Comment: Add the row (4, Hello, Friend). When you order by id, should Hello Friend come before or after Hello Enemy?

Comment: Essentially - this is not possible since you are selecting distinct values from col1 and col2.  They are not associated with id.  For example there might be 100 col1 of same value with 100 different id's not neccessarily in sequence.

Comment: `distinct on ()` maybe? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=416e746b6e5bd613192f2e6f34394b2c

Comment: I reverted your edit. If you have a new (or different) question, ask a new question. Don't change an existing question completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation, and put an aggregate function in the `order by` clause:

```
select col1, col2 from mytable group by col1, col2 order by min(id) limit 10
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `order by min(id) limit 10` matches *top ten most distinct*...

Comment: @Akina: it is actually unclear to me what *top ten most distinct* means, but surely OP can adust the sort direction as needed.

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do it:

```
select A.col1, A.col2
from 
(select id, col1, col2
from Tablet
order by id) A
left join 
(select min(id) id2, col1, col2
from Tablet
GROUP BY COL1, COL2) B
on A.COL1 = B.COL1 AND A.COL2=b.COL2
where A.id = B.id2
LIMIT 4;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=84f37035d9e0fc2f3d39bbb5d12b8725)

Comment: *I have updated my answer and my DEMO* It is not correct too. Primarily remember that when/if ORDER BY in a subquery is not accompanied by LIMIT then it will be ignored. Always. More precisely, it will be removed from the query text during execution plan building. And so its presence will have no effect. Never. Each time when you obtain the result which looks like correct one due to this ordering presence - it is random. The only exclusion is the case when user-defined variables are used, but in this case the execution is hidden cursor, not a solid query.

Comment: I'll wait. The work of a critic is easy and pleasant. Unlike the work of a poet...

Comment: Sorry... [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3c278f07c971e62ba1345b53fb295b61)

Comment: Now ok. Especially if remove excess fragments `order by id`, `, count(id) CNT` and `cnt = 1 or`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c7a4ea1db532d91b44755d0b3f7f27a2)

Comment: I do not agree with this: "remove order by id", we do not have same results. But I will remove cnt and cnt =1. So now up vote ?

Comment: *I do not agree with this: "remove order by id", we do not have same results.* [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=341af860ec097e542c2152c7069bbbe3) with and without ordering. I see the same 4 records in output (their physical ordering in output doesn't matter). Where is the difference?

Comment: "Where is the difference?" In order. Still no up vote ?

Comment: The order makes no sense if not specified. The output without ordering is a heap. Only the presence or absence of some separate record is a difference.